# Overloading operator[] to start at 1 and performance overhead

Tags: c++, performance

I am doing some C++ computational mechanics (don't worry, no physics knowledge required here) and there is something that really bothers me.

Suppose I want to represent a 3D math Vector (nothing to do with std::vector):

```
class Vector {
    public:
        Vector(double x=0., double y=0., double z=0.) { 
            coordinates[0] = x;
            coordinates[1] = y;
            coordinates[2] = z;
        }
    private:
        double coordinates[3];
};
```

So far so good. Now I can overload operator[] to extract coordinates:

```
double& Vector::operator[](int i) {
     return coordinates[i] ;
}
```

So I can type:

```
Vector V; 

… //complex computation with V

double x1 = V[0];
V[1] = coord2;
```

The problem is, indexing from 0 is NOT natural here. I mean, when sorting arrays, I don't mind, but the fact is that the conventionnal notation in every paper, book or whatever is always substripting coordinates beginning with 1.
It may seem a quibble but the fact is that in formulas, it always takes a double-take to understand what we are taking about. Of course, this is much worst with matrices.

One obvious solution is just a slightly different overloading :

```
double& Vector::operator[](int i) {
     return coordinates[i-1] ;
}
```

so I can type

```
double x1 = V[1];
V[2] = coord2;
```

It seems perfect except for one thing: this i-1 subtraction which seems a good candidate for a small overhead. Very small you would say, but I am doing computationnal mechanics, so this is typically something we couldn't afford.

So now (finally) my question: do you think a compiler can optimize this, or is there a way to make it optimize ? (templates, macro, pointer or reference kludge...)

Logically, in

```
double xi = V[i];
```

the integer between the bracket being a literal most of the time (except in 3-iteration for loops), inlining operator[] should make it possible, right ?

(sorry for this looong question)

EDIT:

Thanks for all your comments and answers

I kind of disagree with people telling me that we are used to 0-indexed vectors.
From an object-oriented perspective, I see no reason for a math Vector to be 0-indexed because implemented with a 0-indexed array. We're not suppose to care about the underlying implementation. Now, suppose I don't care about performance and use a map to implement Vector class. Then I would find it natural to map '1' with the '1st' coordinate.

That said I tried out with 1-indexed vectors and matrices, and after some code writing, I find it not interacting nicely every time I use an array around. I thougth Vector and containers (std::array,std::vector...) would not interact often (meaning, transfering data between one another), but it seems I was wrong.

Now I have of a solution that I think is less controversial (please give me your opinion) :
Every time I use a Vector in some physical context, I think of using an enum :

```
enum Coord {
    x = 0,
    y = 1,
    z = 2
};
Vector V;
V[x] = 1;
```

The only disadvantage I see being that these x,y and z can be redefined without enven a warning...

Comment: Don't do premature optimization. Subtracting one from a number is really not something I'd worry about. If you can *measure*, with a profiler, that it *really* hurts your performances, you can fix your code when you're done.

Comment: If you can cope with the space overhead, make your array one element larger and don't use it. But in programming, starting at 0 /is/ natural, so ever programmer maintaining your code will pull his hairs...

Comment: You could always do something awful like store your array as a pointer and scooch it back by one slot. `double * coordinates; double _coords[3];` and then `coordinates = _coords - 1;` thus coordinates[1] will equal _coords[0]

Comment: @Wug - that would be a much bigger performance overhead than subtracting one.

Comment: @AndreaBergia I would usually say that but this class will be accessed virtually everywhere in the program, the operation will appear almost as often as, say, the + sign! (exaggerated, but you get the idea)

Comment: @JimBuck array indexing consists of a multiply (or shift) and an add anyway (the operation takes an index and a pointer).  I don't see how it will make a difference, unless theres some compiler optimization that would do it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Well actually, I think that if you can be surprised once, this is much more easier later on for understanding. Moreover, many people in the business comes from Fortran where you can index from 1

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul: I would nevertheless then use something else to access the elements than op[]

Comment: +1 For a nice microoptimization question that will drive the "anti-premature-optization"-purists crazy. Even if the initial motive is rather questionable.

Comment: Most processors today have what's called "indirect addressing" that will handle trivial offsets like `i - 1` basically for free anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau & PlasmaHH I understand the strange behaviour might be shocking, but honesly in the business, it feels more natural. I think of this as a physical object, so I don't want to always be remembered its inner implementation

Comment: @Wug - because it would have to load from memory the pointer value stored in `coordinates`.

Comment: then make it const and it will be inlined in the same way that array base addresses are.

Answer (score 11):

This one should be measured or verified by looking at the disassembly, but my guess is: The getter function is tiny and its arguments are constant. There is a high chance the compiler will inline the function and constant-fold the subtraction. In that case the runtime cost would be zero.

Comment: +1 for constant-fold. Accessing a variable generally involves a constant offset from some pointer, and the compiler can combine the constant with the offset.

Comment: @usr just to be sure I understand: V[i] when i const: no overhead, but then  with my for loop ? Does my compiler have a chance to also unfold this loop and inline it ?

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul The 3-item for loop will almost certainly be unrolled (when the loop body is small) or get converted to `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {..}`, with all `V[i-1]`'s getting replaced with `V[i]`, when the loop body is large. You can check the disassembly, but the answer is almost certainly going to be that the compiler is smart enough to figure this one out.

Comment: That is the point where it depends on the compiler. If it unfolds the loop (likely) the indices will become constants. But it becomes much harder now to make a useful statement.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to try this:

```
class Vector {
    public:
        Vector(double x=0., double y=0., double z=0.) { 
            coordinates[1] = x;
            coordinates[2] = y;
            coordinates[3] = z;
        }
    private:
        double coordinates[4];
};
```

If you are not instantiating your object in quantities of millions, then the memory waist might be affordable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually profiled it or examined the generated code? That's how this question is answered.

If the operator[] implementation is visible then this is likely to be optimized to have zero overhead.

Comment: No, I confess I don't know how to read the disassembly. But I also posted to know if there is some well known facts about how the compiler should work

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you define this in the header (.h) for your class.  If you define it in the .cpp then the compiler can't optimize as much.  Also, your index should not be an "int" which can have negative values... make it a size_t:

```
class Vector {

    // ...

public:
    double& operator[](const size_t i) {
        return coordinates[i-1] ;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say anything objective about performance without benchmarking. On x86, this subtraction can be compiled using relative addressing, which is very cheap. If `operator[]` is inlined, then the overhead is zero—you can encourage this with `inline` or with compiler-specific instructions such as GCC’s `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

If you must guarantee it, and the offset is a compile-time constant, then using a template is the way to go:

```
template<size_t I>
double& Vector::get() {
    return coordinates[i - 1];
}

double x = v.get<1>();
```

For all practical purposes, this is guaranteed to have zero overhead thanks to constant-folding. You could also use named accessors:

```
double Vector::x() const { return coordinates[0]; }
double Vector::y() const { return coordinates[1]; }
double Vector::z() const { return coordinates[2]; }

double& Vector::x() { return coordinates[0]; }
double& Vector::y() { return coordinates[1]; }
double& Vector::z() { return coordinates[2]; }
```

And for loops, iterators:

```
const double* Vector::begin() const { return coordinates; }
const double* Vector::end() const { return coordinates + 3; }

double* Vector::begin() { return coordinates; }
double* Vector::end() { return coordinates + 3; }

// (x, y, z) -> (x + 1, y + 1, z + 1)
for (auto& i : v) ++i;
```

Like many of the others here, however, I disagree with the premise of your question. You really should simply use 0-based indexing, as it is more natural in the realm of C++. The language is already very complex, and you need not complicate things further for those who will maintain your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, benchmark this all three ways (ie, compare the subtraction and the double[4] methods to just using zero-based indices in the caller).

It's entirely possible you'll get a huge win from forcing 16-byte alignment on some cache architectures, and equally possible the subtraction is effectively free on some compiler/instruction set/code path combinations.

The *only* way to tell is to benchmark realistic code.